# Write linq query to get records satisfying a condition

Tags: c#, json, linq, indexing, json-deserialization

I need to write a linq query to get all records from index file for which the `(CompRecordPosition == 0 and DPNbr!=0) || (CompRecordPosition!=0)`.I have written the query as below but the debugger is getting stuck at this line without proceeding further. Please help to get only those index records to `_wIndex` variable satisfying the given condition

```
private List<WIndex> _wIndex;
private readonly string _FilePath;
internal const string _Key = "Test";

string idxData = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(_FilePath, _Key + ".ind"));
_wIndex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WIndex>>(idxData);

_wIndex = _wIndex.Where(p2=>_wIndex
    .Any(p1 => (p2.CompletionRecordPosition == 0  && p2.WbNewestDrlPmtNbr!=0) || 
    p2.CompletionRecordPosition!=0)).ToList();
```

WIndex Class

```
public class WIndex
{
    public string BaNo;
    public long RecordPosition;
    public long CompRecordPosition;
    public long SegRecordPosition;
    public string DataType;
    public int RecordIndex;
    public Int32 DpNbr;
}
```

Index file

```
  [{
    "BaNo": "7000650000",
    "RecordPosition": 345,
    "CompRecordPosition": 567,
    "SegRecordPosition": 788,
    "DataType": "WELL",
    "RecordIndex": 0,
    "DPNbr": 0
  },
  {
    "BaNo": "7000790001",
    "RecordPosition": 800,
    "CompRecordPosition": 0,
    "SegRecordPosition": 0,
    "DataType": "WELL",
    "RecordIndex": 1,
    "DPNbr": 810
  }]
```

Comment: Can I suggest you put `p2.CompletionRecordPosition!=0` on the left-hand side of the or so that you can avoid evaluating the `.Any` when this condition is met?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "getting stuck" because that seems very unlikely. An error seems possible, but getting stuck really doesn't in this scenario.

Comment: At the moment your query is really just `_wIndex.Any(p => p.CompletionRecordPosition == 0)`

Comment: remove the any(), `var newlist = _wIndex.Where(x => x.CompletionRecordPosition == 0 
        && x.WbNewestDrlPmtNbr != 0
      ).ToList();` ??

Comment: the `_wIndex.Any(p1 => ...` looks odd. `p1` does not seem to be used anywhere? And what is the actual error? "debugger is getting stuck" might just be because it is super slow.

Comment: the query is looping over the loop once for each entry, hence its taking foreva, if this was intended then probably just better to write as foreach over foreach, so the query can be better visualized then tweaked with some joins

Comment: so my comment was the answer great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some questions raised in the linq statement you are trying to execute:

Why use a `where` then immediately an `any` clause within the where clause. My recommendation is to eliminate the any clause as its not need to collect items you are requesting from the list.

`Any()` - Determines whether an element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition.

`Where()` - Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

Making the statement something like `_wIndex.Where(x => x.CompletionRecordPosition == 0 && x.WbNewestDrlPmtNbr != 0).ToList();` would likely be something more preferrable.

Also, `.Any(p1 => ...` here `p1` is never used or indicated later in any of the lambda expressions. The `input parameter` can be removed as the relation between `p1` and `p2` never correlates between the sets. Most likely causing the debug to sit and spin trying to determine what is needed.

Let me know if this helps - thanks.